# Trouble with returning int[] to main also with finding mode

Tags: java, methods

so my program finds the mean, median, mode, tand dev, quartiles and store a 5 num summary as an array(`min,max,mid,upper and lower quartile`)

The main just creates a `randNum[]` and prints the methods.

The method on mode is supposed to return -1 if there is no mode of if there are multiple modes.

In the 5 num summary in getting incompatible types "`found int[]  required int`"

How do I send an array of ints to main ??

```
import java.util.*;

class Statistics
  {



 //==============================================================
//---------------------------MEAN-------------------------------- 
  public static double mean(int [] v)
  { 
    double sum= 0 ;
    double  mean = 0 ;
    for(double w : v)
    {
      sum += w; 
    }
    mean = sum/v.length; 

    return mean;
  }
//==============================================================
//-----------------------------MODE----------------------------- 

public static int mode(int[] v)
 {

  int modeCount = 0,mode = 0, currCount = 0,currElement;


 for (int candidateMode : v)
  {
   currCount = 0;


   for (int element : v)
   {

    if (candidateMode == element)
    {
     currCount++;
    }
   }


   if (currCount > modeCount)
   {
    modeCount = currCount;
    mode = candidateMode;
   }
 } 
  return mode;

 }

  //==============================================================
 //------------------------MIN / MAX / MEDIAN -------------------- 


public static int min(int[] v)
 {
  int min1 = v[0];
  return min1; 
 }
 public static int max(int[] v)
 {
  int max1 = v[4];
  return max1; 
 }

 public static int median(int[]v)
 {
   int mid = v.length / 2;
   return mid;
 }




   //==============================================================
   //-------------------------Standard Deviation-------------------  

 public static double stanDev(int[] v)
 {
    double val = 0,adding = 0, divide = 0, answer = 0, square= 0 ;
    double sum= 0 ;
    double  mean = 0 ;
    for(double w : v)
    {
      sum += w; 
    }
    mean = sum/v.length; 
        for ( double r : v){ 
          val =   r - mean;
          square  = val* val;
          adding += square ;
          divide = adding /100;
          answer = Math.sqrt(divide);

      }
        return answer;
 }
 //==============================================================
 //-------------------------Quartile----------------------------- 


 public static int quartile(int[] v, int upOrLow)
 {
       int[] vv = new int[v.length];
        System.arraycopy(v, 0, vv, 0, v.length);
        Arrays.sort(vv);

        int n = (int) Math.round(vv.length * upOrLow / 100);

        return vv[n];

    }

  //==============================================================
 //-------------------------5 NUM SUMMARY------------------------- 


 public static int summ(int [] v)
 {
       int[] vv = new int[v.length];
        System.arraycopy(v, 0, vv, 0, v.length);
        Arrays.sort(vv);

        int n = (int) Math.round(vv.length * 25 / 100);
        int n1 = (int) Math.round(vv.length * 75 / 100);
        int n2 = v[0];
        int n3 = v[49];
        int n4 = v[99];

        int[] vals1 = {n,n1,n2,n3,n4};

        return vals1;


}
}
```

```
//============================================================================== 
//===================MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN========================       
//================================================================================


import java.util.*;


public class Main
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {

    Random rand = new Random();

    int [] v = new int[100];

    for( int i = 0; i < v.length ; i++)
    {
      v[i] = rand.nextInt(489)+10;
    }
    Arrays.sort(v);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
    System.out.println("The mean is: " + Statistics.mean(v));
    System.out.println("The mode is: " + Statistics.mode(v));
    System.out.println("The min value is: " + Statistics.min(v));
    System.out.println("The max value is: " + Statistics.max(v));
    System.out.println("The max value is: " + Statistics.median(v));
    System.out.println("The Standard Dev. value is: " + Statistics.stanDev(v));
    System.out.println("The lower quartile value is: " + Statistics.quartile(v,25));
    System.out.println("The upper quartile value is: " + Statistics.quartile(v,75));
    System.out.println("The  number summary is: " + Statistics.summ(v));
}
}
```

Comment: By declaring it as `public static int[] summ(int [] v)`?

Comment: aahaha !!!  thank you ! lol ... do you know a way to do the mode by any chance ?

Comment: @JeremiahParrack what if there is more than one number that has the most repeated instances? Will you only get the first one that is found?

Comment: @Ediac no if more than one repeated  return -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mode you can apply the following modifications:

```
public static int mode(int[] v)
{
    int modeCount = 0,mode = 0, currCount = 0;
    boolean thereIsMode = false;
    boolean ModeIsRepeated = false;

    for (int candidateMode : v)
    {
        if(candidateMode == mode)
            continue;

        currCount = 0;

        for (int element : v)
        {
            if (candidateMode == element)
            {
                currCount++;
            }
        }

        if (currCount > modeCount)
        {
            modeCount = currCount;
            mode = candidateMode;
            thereIsMode = true;
            ModeIsRepeated = false;
        }
        else if( currCount == modeCount && candidateMode != mode )
        {
            ModeIsRepeated = true;
        }
    } 

    if( !thereIsMode || ModeIsRepeated ){
        return -1;
    }

    return mode;
}
```

I deleted `currElement` as that was unused, and added two new variables `thereIsMode` and `ModeIsRepeated` . Practically `thereIsMode` is to tell whether the array is empty or not, as if it isn't empty there will always be at least 1 mode. `ModeIsRepeated` does what its name says, and it is reset to `false` every time a new mode is detected.

Also added:

```
if(candidateMode == mode)
    continue;
```

To jump to the next loop if the current candidate is the same as mode, as checking it is unnecessary.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I am going to study the code it works though. Thank you again.